# Asyncio wait between tasks

Tags: python, request, python-asyncio, thread-sleep

I would like to wait between each group of 50 tasks to respect limit of APIs requests, but the sleep doesn't work. Do you have an idea. This is my code :

```
nb_tasks = len(tasks)
nb_page = (nb_tasks // 50) + 1

for i in range(nb_page):
    if (i + 1 * 50) < nb_tasks:
        tasks_to_play = tasks[i * 50: -1]
    else:
        tasks_to_play = tasks[i * 50: i + 1 * 50]

    print("TIME : " + str(config.time_to_reset))

    asyncio.gather(*tasks_to_play)
    time.sleep(config.time_to_reset)
```

Thank you

Comment: How do you create your tasks? If you use `create_task`, you schedule them with the event loop immediately.

Comment: I create task with create_task and ensure_future. How to insert breaks (sleep time) between each task or a group of several tasks? To avoid exceeding the API call quota.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: When you construct `tasks`, just stick the coroutines in there (rather than creating tasks for them) and gather 50 of them at a time. That won’t schedule them with the end loop until you await `gather`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean by "stick the coroutines in there" ?

Comment: Don’t use things like `create_task`. Instead do something like `tasks = [request(url1), request(url2)]`.

Answer (score 0):

u need to use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep`, but your logic here doesn't exactly accomplish your goal, for example if the endpoint has a rate limit of 50 per second, but your `asyncio.gather(...)` takes 5 seconds to complete, not only did u miss out on 200 extra requests u could have scheduled, but even after they complete you will sleep and waste more time before making more requests

u could schedule them in blocks like u did with a `gather` but i think simply spreading them out with constant gaps and gathering the results is much cleaner i.e.

```py
RATE_LIMIT_PER_SECOND = 50

async def main():
    many_tasks = ...
    pending_tasks = list()
    for task in many_tasks:
        pending_tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(task))
        await asyncio.sleep(1 / RATE_LIMIT_PER_SECOND)
    results = await asyncio.gather(*pending_tasks)
    print(results)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Hey Avi, I tried this, but didn't work, there is no wait between task, so I don't respect the limit.

Comment: @JasonBeni here it waits 0.02 seconds between scheduling each task, have u tried decreasing the `RATE_LIMIT_PER_SECOND`?

Comment: I tried with a sleep time of 1 second, and didn’t work. Don’t seems to sleep at all. Do you have another idea ?

Comment: just doing `await asyncio.sleep(1)` doesn't wait for a second? what happens when u do `python -c "import asyncio; asyncio.run(asyncio.sleep(1))"`? it should sleep for a second